# Ionic 2 - Status Bar

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic2

Não estou conseguindo mudar a cor da minha Status Bar com o Ionic 2. Conferi a documentação e estou fazendo o seguinte.

app.js

```
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
```

app.js (constructor())

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(#f69c55);
});
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Vc executou o comando ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A configuração está correta. Porém, meu dispositivo era Android 5.0 e a StautsBar funciona apenas em versões posteriores a essa, como especifica a documentação.

> This installation method requires cordova 5.0+

Answer (score 1):

Se você se refere ao Toolbar eu consegui adicionando o meu estilo no arquivo `/src/theme/global.scss`

```
//------- TOOLBAR //-------
    .toolbar-title-md, .bar-button-default-md, .bar-button-clear-md-default, .bar-button-md-default, .toolbar-title-ios {
        color: color($colors, minhaCor);
    }
    .toolbar-background-md, .toolbar-background-ios {
        background: none;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/Status%20Bar/
A documentação faz a seguinte observação:

Set the status bar to a specific hex color (CSS shorthand supported!).

**iOS note:** you must call StatusBar.overlaysWebView(**false**) to enable color changing.

O seu ta true

Answer (score 0):

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(#f69c55);
```

Esta forma esta incorreta, pois pela documentação tem que ser um valor 'STRING'. O jeito certo de uso é:

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#f69c55');
```

Answer (score -2):

Troca o **true** pelo **false** que vai dar certo!